# Como arrumar JSON sem aspas nos index

Tags: php, json

Tenho o seguinte JSON que veio de um JavaScript e estou usando ele no PHP. Estou dando `json_decode($json)`, mas obviamente não funciona. Pois não há aspas no *index* de cada valor.

```
   options: [
          {
            value: "120",
            id: "40",
            title: "1400g",
            name: "Tamanho"
          },
          {
            value: "336",
            id: "60",
            title: "Chocolate",
            name: "Sabor"
          }
        ]
```

Como posso corrigir isso no PHP?

Comment: Como esse JSON chega ao PHP? O ideal seria tratar isso por quem está enviando, não por quem está recebendo. Se você está enviando por JavaScript, um `JSON.stringify` deveria gerar um JSON válido.

Comment: Estou lendo o DOM de uma página de um produto e o JSON está no dentro de um javascript que é utilizado na página, não tenho como escolher como vou receber infelizmente

Comment: Deu certo Vitor? Se funcionou a resposta. Coloque-a como certa. Aconselho você a escolher a resposta do LipESprY. ✔

Comment: Dê uma olhada na [sintaxe de JSON](https://www.json.org) para ver que o que você tem é **no máximo** um pedaço incompleto de um JSON. Talvez vc devesse voltar um passo e repensar se essa é a melhor solução para o que quer que esteja tentando fazer, pois pegar um trecho incompleto de JavaScript e tentar interpretar no PHP não parece uma boa abordagem.

Comment: É realmente um pedaço do json, afinal o json tem mais de 1000 posições então não tem muito como postar aqui, vou testar o do LipESprY e ja odu o upvote se der certo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "*- Tenho o seguinte JSON [...]*"

Não. Isso não é um JSON!

[image: jsonlint.com]

Você pode validar este e outros JSON no [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/).

---

> "*- [...] não há aspas no index de cada valor [...] Como posso corrigir isso no PHP?*"

---

> "*- Se você está enviando por JavaScript, um JSON.stringify deveria gerar um JSON válido.*" - [@user140828](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/140828/user140828)

---

> "*- não tenho como escolher como vou receber infelizmente*"

Então o jeito é apelar para uma "**gambiarra**"...

Considerando que o seu "JSON" siga *sempre* este padrão, você pode definir uma simples expressão regular para "adicionar as aspas":

```
$json = '{'.preg_replace('/(\w+)(\:)/', '\"$1\"$2', $json).'}';
```

Veja a expressão funcionando no [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gz6HzJ/1).

Comment: o seu regex está melhor que o meu!

Comment: preciso treinar isso ai... todo mundo faz regex melhor que eu... XD kkkk

Comment: Espere então até o [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) aparecer aí e dar uma bendita aula sobre RegEx! kkkk

Comment: Sim! Ai já era... Perdemos... =)

Comment: Mas a sua resposta é a correta!

Comment: @Andrei Não consideraria a parte da gambiarra uma resposta correta. É mais uma gambiarra mesmo! Kkkk

Comment: Haha! Bom, não tenho o que acrescentar, talvez só um detalhe: se o valor tiver `:` entre as aspas, aí o replace produz um JSON inválido, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/gz6HzJ/2) (e uma [possível solução](https://regex101.com/r/7ppHhs/3)). Mas como não ficou claro se isso pode acontecer, então a sua regex resolve. E não acho que é gambiarra, o problema é o fato de estar pegando um trecho de JavaScript (e nem é um trecho completo, pois em JS também não é um objeto válido), então a abordagem já parece que começou errada, aí nenhuma solução será boa :-)

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Eu sugiro [esse site](http://rexegg.com) e [esse tb](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), tem exemplos muito bons. E [esse livro](https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124) é considerado uma das "bíblias" de regex (e esse vai fundo mesmo, ainda não consegui entender tudo...)

Comment: É! Justamente por isso eu disse que "se seguir sempre esse padrão" são se útil. E sim, tudo começou errado! Kkkk

Comment: @hkotsubo valeu mestre! Vou ver sim!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer um replace com um regex. Assim:

```
$jsonEstranho = 'options: [
      {
        value: "120",
        id: "40",
        title: "1400g",
        name: "Tamanho"
      },
      {
        value: "336",
        id: "60",
        title: "Chocolate",
        name: "Sabor"
      }
]';

// retira todas as aspas duplas
$jsonEstranho = str_replace('"', "", $jsonEstranho); 
// insere aspas duplas em tudo que não vor um caracter do Json e colo chaves no inicio e no fim
$jsonCorreto = "{".preg_replace('/(\w+)/', '"$0"', $jsonEstranho)."}";  

print_r(json_decode($jsonCorreto));
```

[Veja funcionando](https://ideone.com/STpQmU)

Comment: +1 pelo `$jsonEstranho`! kkkk

Comment: @LipESprY kkkkkk